# C++ : mixing Directx9 and default windows

Tags: c++, windows, directx

I am looking for a method of placing a DXLinked window within a windowproc as a child window. This would allow for menus/Forms controls to be externally managed before input to the DX methods.

So far I have attempted to create two WNDCLASSEX and two HWND types, and ran both windowprocs in the main loop. This unfortunately doesn't seem to work.

A screen shot example of what I wish to accomplish.
http://clip2net.com/s/3jXUG2l - a well known modding tool that is used for Lua and C++ code attachments for objects.

Appreciate any feedback.

Relevant code I am currently using as a prototype:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d9.h>


#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")


LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;    
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev; 
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 v_buffer = NULL;    


void initD3D(HWND hWnd);  
void render_frame(void);   
void cleanD3D(void);    
void init_graphics(void);    // 3D declarations

struct CUSTOMVERTEX { FLOAT X, Y, Z, RHW; DWORD COLOR; };
#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM     lParam);

//Main
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine,
int nCmdShow)
{
HWND hWnd;
WNDCLASSEX wc;

ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

RegisterClassEx(&wc);

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
    L"WindowClass",
    L"DirectX Test",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    300, 300,
    800, 600,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

initD3D(hWnd);

MSG msg;

while (TRUE)
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        break;

    render_frame();
}

// clean up DirectX and COM
cleanD3D();

return msg.wParam;
}


// t
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_DESTROY:
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
} break;
}

return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: As this is a programming question )

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) referred in prior comment? "If your code or your IDE doesn't work, ask on..." etc

Comment: Yup, this code works fine: it is simply an example.
As such this question fits all criteria for posting on this site.

Comment: @JamieNicholl-Shelley this question does _not_ fit all criteria for posting on this site. You need help writing code, whether the code you have currently works or not. That is not a conceptual programming problem.

Comment: I am N.O.T asking for help writing code.Alas I give up.

Comment: It's not at all clear what your question is. Your first sentence doesn't make sense. A window can't be within a windows procedure, and what is "DXLinked" supposed to mean? Your sample code is a red herring. It doesn't show what you're trying to do or what you've tried to do. If you're not asking for help implementing something like the image you posted (ie. writing code) then your post makes even less sense.

Comment: Mmm I can now see how some could see this question differently. Apologies I made assumptions of others abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, I made some incorrect assumptions.
Appreciate the feedback however.